# C# Excel.Interop Detecting a Sort Action

Tags: c#, .net, excel, sorting, com-interop

I have looked at the various levels(application, workbook, and worksheet) of the Excel.Interop libraries to find out how to detect a user sorting data. I have created a class that instantiates an application, workbook, and worksheet. The program has data piped in from another application and then adds it to a worksheet. I am using .NET 4.5, C# compiler version 4.0, and have been testing with Excel 2013 if that makes a difference.

I can detect cell changes and calculation events but neither of those events fire when a column is sorted. I believed that it should work after reading this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/05/03/handling-sort-and-filter-events-in-excel-navneet-gupta.aspx).

After having that fail for me, I looked into the [table update event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.docevents_event.tableupdate.aspx) but I had no luck. There error I received was along the lines of, "the handler does not exist in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace, are you missing an assembly. I don't think this is the right direction I need to go but I was attempting to see if it would suit my needs.

Using any other method besides the Excel Interop method might set me back a few weeks.

Is there something I am missing in regards to the table update event handler or perhaps the sort event itself?